# unfamiliar with struct/class declaration with template

Tags: c++, templates, struct

while going through some of the [mili](http://code.google.com/p/mili/) source code I came across a struct declared like this:

```
template <class T, class Pre, class Pos>
struct PrePosCaller<T*, Pre, Pos>
```

(from [here](http://code.google.com/p/mili/source/browse/trunk/mili/prepos_caller.h))

The part I'm unfamiliar with is `<T*, Pre, Pos>`. I understand what the code does and its purpose in this context but I would like to know **where it is documented** so I can learn/understand it a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a template specialization. In particular a *partial specialization*.

Somewhere in the code there is a template declared as:

```
template <class T, class Pre, class Pos>
struct PrePosCaller { //...
};
```

or something similar. Then they are providing an specialization of that template for the cases where the first argument is a pointer type. That is, this is a template definition for `PrePosCaller` when the first argument of the template is a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know where it is documented

If you are looking for an introduction as well as background to the subject, get yourself a copy of [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842).
While the definitive documentation is the C++ standard itself, its no fun to approach it without a well written overview.

Answer (score 1):

[Thinking in C++ Vol. 2](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) provides a pedagogical view on templates and some related techniques. It is also an excellent read about C++ in general. And it is free.